# Excel not propagating values changed while file closed, not updating calculations, formulae

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

An xlsx file is essentially a zip of XML files and such.  I have an xlsx file that is modified by another, not-Excel program.  It updates values on sheet A.  Sheet B has formulae based on values on sheet A.  When Excel opens the file it doesn't realize the formula inputs have changed while the file was closed from Excel's PoV.  Of course the not-Excel program opens the file modifies the values and closes the file.  But Excel doesn't know that.  So it doesn't recalculate.  How can I tell Excel the values have changed and to recalculate the formulae?  How do I get it to recalculate?

I have tried all the usual recalc bugs suggested by Google:
• checking all parentheses in formulae
• making sure all required arguments are supplied to functions
• do not nest more than 64 functions in a formula
• don't enclose numbers in double quotes
• when using a number in an Excel formula, don't add any decimal separator or currency sign like $ or €
• make sure numbers are not formatted as text values (they're General)
• separate function arguments with a proper character
• enclose workbook and worksheet names in single quotes (they are)
• include the full path to a closed workbook (only references another sheet, not another workbook)
• Calculation Options is set to automatic
• tried pressing "Calculate Now"
• tried pressing "Calculate Sheet"
• tried pressing F9
• tried pressing Shift+F9
• Show Formulas mode is turned off
• The formula is not entered as Text
• the formula does not have a leading space

If I edit the formula by clicking the end of the formula and hitting enter it thinks the formula has changed and evaluates the formula correctly.  But it would be tedious to do this for every cell in the table every time the data changes to force it to reevaluate the formulae.

In the Formulas menu, if I hit Evaluate Formula >> Evaluate the dialog shows the correct, new value for the formula.  But when I close the dialog the value in the sheet hasn't changed, of course.

The formulae are simple, like:
`='trailing 12 months years'!D4`

[image]

The trouble is Excel doesn't know cell 'trailing 12 months years'!D4 was changed while the file was closed (from Excel's PoV).

So how do you get Excel to recalculate?

Comment: Try to use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F9` or `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`F9`

Comment: Another trick is to replace `=` by `=` for the entire workbook. Doesn't change anything, but it forces Excel to recalculate everything.

Comment: @MGonet that worked, Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9  Thanks!!